# datasnapshot not get data?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            List<Object> driverLocationMap = (List<Object>) snapshot.getValue();
            double LocationLat = 0;
            double LocationLng = 0;

            vanfind.setText("Driver Found");

            if (driverLocationMap.get(0) != null) {
                LocationLat = Double.parseDouble(driverLocationMap.get(0).toString());

            }
            if (driverLocationMap.get(1) != null) {
                LocationLng = Double.parseDouble(driverLocationMap.get(1).toString());

            }

            LatLng DriverLatLng = new LatLng(LocationLat, LocationLng);
            if (DriverMarker != null) {
                DriverMarker.remove();
            }

            Location location1 = new Location("");
            location1.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            location1.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

            Location location2 = new Location("");
            location2.setLatitude(DriverLatLng.latitude);
            location2.setLongitude(DriverLatLng.longitude);

            float Distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
            vanfind.setText("Driver Found:" + String.valueOf(Distance));

            DriverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DriverLatLng).title("your Driver is here"));


        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

After `driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l")` line no code is executed. I check it in debugger console, but its not working after first line below code is not executed.

Its Uber Or Cream like app. Everything is okay, but this datasnapshot is not getting data not working.

Comment: Are you sure  that "driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l")" exist?

Comment: Steps to debug this: 1) put a breakpoint on `if (snapshot.exists()) {` and run in the debugger. Does it hit this line? If so, step through the code from there. 2) **never** leave `onCancelled` empty, as you're ignoring errors. At its minimum, this should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: if(snapshot.exits()) not hit

Comment: only first line driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 is hit below no other cod eis hit

Comment: yes it exist Unknown_2433 it show in debugger after that no other code is running

Comment: Stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write it like:

```
final DatabaseReference
driverLocationRef = Firebasedatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(driverFoundID).child("l");
```

Then you can go ahead and write

```
driverLocationRef.addOnCompleteListener...
```

Comment: It is not working i write final but not working

Comment: Have you checked your spelling if they match with firebase rdb?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use interface for fetching `LocationLat` and `LocationLng`. Then do all your work inside `onCallBack`.
Declare a interface like this:

```
public interface MyCallback{
    void onCallback(double LocationLat,double LocationLng);
}
```

then wrap your listener inside a function

```
public void getData(final MyCallback myCallback){
    driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                List<Object> driverLocationMap = (List<Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                double LocationLat = 0;
                double LocationLng = 0;

                vanfind.setText("Driver Found");

                if (driverLocationMap.get(0) != null) {
                    LocationLat = Double.parseDouble(driverLocationMap.get(0).toString());

                }
                if (driverLocationMap.get(1) != null) {
                    LocationLng = Double.parseDouble(driverLocationMap.get(1).toString());
                }
                myCallback.onCallback(LocationLat,LocationLng);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

Then call function like this when you need:

```
getData(new MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(double LocationLat, double LocationLng) {
            LatLng DriverLatLng = new LatLng(LocationLat, LocationLng);
            if (DriverMarker != null) {
                DriverMarker.remove();
            }

            Location location1 = new Location("");
            location1.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            location1.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);

            Location location2 = new Location("");
            location2.setLatitude(DriverLatLng.latitude);
            location2.setLongitude(DriverLatLng.longitude);

            float Distance = location1.distanceTo(location2);
            vanfind.setText("Driver Found:" + String.valueOf(Distance));

            DriverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(DriverLatLng).title("your Driver is here"));
        }
    });
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: 1st I create an interface then I paste the first code in it then what?

Comment: where i paste that code   public void getData(final MyCallback myCallback){
    driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                List<Object> driverLocationMap = (List<Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                double LocationLat = 0;
                double LocationLng = 0;

                vanfind.setText("Driver Found");

Comment: please reply when u online

Comment: Paste first 2 code anywhere outside of your `oncreate` method. Then paste the 3rd code when you want to get data from database. Suppose you are calling `your code` inside `oncreate method`. Now for my code, paste the first two code anywhere outside oncreate and paste the third code `inside oncreate method`.

Comment: my 2nd code will retrieve data from database. And `onCallBack` in 3rd code(when you paste 3rd code) will be called when data retrieve is finished. Then, code inside `onCallBack` inside `3rd code` will be executed.

Comment: okk. after trying, notify if its working or not.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pick_drop/com.example.pick_drop.customersidedetail.CustomerSideActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
        at com.example.pick_drop.customersidedetail.CustomerSideActivity.getData(CustomerSideActivity.java:163)
        at com.example.pick_drop.customersidedetail.CustomerSideActivity.onCreate(CustomerSideActivity.java:133)

Comment: driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID).child("l").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
163 line

Comment: getData(new MyCallback() {
 133 line

Comment: I think `driverFoundID` is null. Add `System.out.println(String.valueOf(driverFoundID));` inside `public void getData` before `driverLocationRef.child(driverFoundID)...` and check in log if it is null or not

Comment: Have you initialized `driverFoundID` before my 3rd code?

Comment: driverFoundID is null

Comment: no i intialized it in as u write in 2nd code it is initialzed value get in 2nd code area

Comment: Can you share the code of your `oncreate method`?